# How to fix ReactJs Sass Not Compiling and error showing in vs code?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use sass in my reactjs project and I tried

`npm install node-sass`
after install and import it with scss extension but not working it, 
I used [W3Schools Tutorial but still not working](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_sass.asp)

error showing this

```
./src/myStyle.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/myStyle.scss)

To import Sass files, you first need to install node-sass.
Run `npm install node-sass` or `yarn add node-sass` inside your workspace.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is:

> Run `npm install node-sass` or `yarn add node-sass` inside your workspace.

This means that the node-sass was not found inside the node_modules folder of the reactjs project.

This problem can be fixed by explicitly installing node-sass inside the project folder (using --save option along with npm install inside the project folder)

1. cd react-js-project-folder
2. npm install --save node-sass

**npm install --save node-sass** must be run in the root of the react-js project, I.E., at the same folder where package.json is located.

Comment: node_modules or src or public folder, I am too much confuse,

Comment: npm install --save node-sass must be run in the root of the react-js project, I.E., at the same folder where package.json is located.